When I average loadings from a PCA why do the "groups" change order?
I conducted a PCA in R using prcomp. The resulting PCA had distinct "groups" at 11 oclock, 9 oclock etc. I then averaged the loadings between these two groups to get a cleaner graph; however the order of the groups change place dramatically after doing so. I don't understand how this happens.
The code I used is below:
loadings <- as.data.frame(res.pca$rotation)
loadings$Variable <- rownames(loadings)
group_definitions <- list(group1 = c("protein1", "protein2"), 
                          group2 = c("protein3"), 
                          group3 = c("protein4", "protein5",
                                                   "protein6", "protein7"), 
                          group4 = c("protein8", "protein9"))
...etc (14 groups)

loadings$Group <- NA
for (group_name in names(group_definitions)) {
  loadings$Group[loadings$Variable %in% group_definitions[[group_name]]] <- group_name
}

avg_loadings <- loadings %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("PC"), mean, na.rm = TRUE))

avg_loadings_biplot <- avg_loadings %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("PC"), names_to = "PC", values_to = "Loading") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = PC, values_from = Loading) %>%
  mutate(Variable = Group)

grouped.res.pca <- res.pca
grouped.res.pca$rotation <- as.matrix(avg_loadings_biplot)
rownames(grouped.res.pca$rotation) <- avg_loadings_biplot$Variable

g <- ggbiplot::ggbiplot(grouped.res.pca,
                        obs.scale = 1,
                        var.scale = 1,
)


